# Can I write an entire book in Sans Serif?

Tags: fonts, book, sans-serif

I want to use FiraSans for my entire book. Is that legal? I heard that one has to choose a serif font for body content. But I really like FiraSans. Oh, I am so confused :'(

Comment: Lots of books on architecture and art are set entirely in sans-serif fonts. They’re perfectly legible, but the sans-serif is part of the book’s expression. If your book is a novel about British gentry in the 1700s, a sans-serif would be completely incongruous and out of place; if it’s about modern Japanese design, it would be fine. And Fira is a very legible and highly usable font, so it’s a good sans to go with.

Comment: There are no laws anywhere in the free world which dictate which kind of font you should use for a book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no law stating what font you can or can not use **anywhere**. You are free to use whatever font you want.

**If you wish to use a sans serif typeface, then by all means do so.**

---

That being said, *books* and items with a great deal of smaller text are traditionally set in a *serif* font for a reason, which *may* ultimately be more preference than science.

Many believe serif fonts are easier on the *reader*. The theory is that the serifs help the eye smoothly transition from one character or word to the next. Meaning serifs help create a even flow while reading. Serif fonts are also often seen as more friendly, softer, and inviting. Where as sans serif fonts are often perceived as more informational in nature.

**Be aware, this is a topic that is often debated among designers.** There's no definitive hard science or study stating serif or sans-serif is "better" than the other. Ease of reading and perception is *very* dependent upon the *viewer's* preference. There's no way to quantify that with any sort of absolute.

So, something such as font choice can depend upon the anticipated audience for a design. Different demographics may have different preferences.

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-typography-determines-readability-serif-vs-sans-serif-and-how-to-combine-fonts-629a51ad8cce/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4612630/
- [https://designshack.net/articles/typography/serif-vs-sans-serif-fonts-is-one-really-better-than-the-other/#:~:text=Readability%20studies%20have%20actually%20found,the%20eye%20to%20recognize%20quickly](https://designshack.net/articles/typography/serif-vs-sans-serif-fonts-is-one-really-better-than-the-other/#:%7E:text=Readability%20studies%20have%20actually%20found,the%20eye%20to%20recognize%20quickly).

Ultimately, as with any design, the choice of what font you use comes down to **what you feel** conveys your "mood" or "message" the best and will be most attractive and inviting to readers. Remember, the typeface you choose isn't about what *you like*. It should be about the reader and audience and the impression you wish to make.

Rest assured, no one files criminal charges over an "illegal" font choice.

Comment: Rare. I have to downvote this post because I absolutely disagree with the statement that serif fonts are easier on the reader. They have been traditionally used for books, yes, but afaik, they are equally legible compared to sans. Worse, some serifs like slabs are *way worse*.

Comment: One bit of research I read long ago suggested that what's most legible to any given audience depends, at least in part, on what they're most accustomed to seeing. The gist of it was that because sans-serif fonts (at least at the time) were more common in Europe than here, sans-serif was more acceptable there for body text. I can say from personal experience that for people with under-corrected astigmatism, sans-serif can be a nightmare in body-text sizes. On the other hand, and at about the same time, I had some software manuals set in Optima that were a dream to read. Go figure.

Comment: @Vincent edited to seem less rule-based and more preference-based. It wasn't my intention to appear to post "no you can't" or to dissuade from sans serif... merely present the mind set of many regarding serifs. Which I do happen to agree with overall.

Comment: @Scott That's a great improvement, thanks! -1 -> +1. And yes, this is highly subjective, with a pretty obvious split between the Anlgo-Saxon world preferring serif and Europe preferring sans. I guess it really also depends on what you were taught to read with: here in the Netherlands, we learned to read with Helvetica ever since the early 80s.

Comment: @Vincent Obvious split? Really? At least here in Scandinavia (and also in the limited selection of books I have here at home which are printed in countries like France, Spain and Germany), for long sequences of text intended to be read continuously (i.e., books, reports, newspapers, academic papers, etc.), serif absolutely dominates and sans-serif is rare. Encyclopaedias, dictionaries, marketing brochures, letters, catalogues and such can go either way, but that’s the case in the Anglosphere as well.

Answer (score 1):

Karen Cheng is an extremely well respected type designer and typographer, and she set her outstanding book «designing type» entirely in a sans-serif font.

I think it makes the book harder to read, but:

- real typographers do it, it's not that uncommon;
- it's not criminal;
- it may be unusual or harm readability, it depends what sort of book it is.